# Exibir 3 numeros em ordem crescente

Tags: javascript

Preciso que o usuário entre com 3 valores e eu mostre  para o usuário os três valores ordenados crescentemente.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> </title> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var idade1, idade2, idade3;

idade1 = prompt ("Informe a primeira idade: ")
idade1 = eval (idade1)

idade2 = prompt ("Informe a segunda idade: ")
idade2 = eval (idade2)

idade3 = prompt ("Informe a terceira idade: ")
idade3 = eval (idade3)




</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de fazer isso seria com um *array* e usar o [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var idade = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) idade[i] = prompt("Informe a primeira idade: ");
idade.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) console.log(idade[i]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Sort.js).