# Calcular media entre 3 notas

Tags: javascript, operadores, sintaxe

Preciso que, o usuário informe 3 notas, para se calcular a media, e informe se ele está aprovado, reprovado, ou de recuperação. acredito que o erro esteja na média em si.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>  </title>


<script type="text/javascript">

var media, n1, n2, n3 ;

n1= prompt ("Informe a primeira nota: ") ;
n1= eval (n1) ;

n2= prompt ("Informe a segunda nota: ") ;
n2= eval (n2) ; 

n3= prompt ("Informe a terceira nota: ") ; 
n3= eval (n3) ;

media = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3 ; 

if ( media >= 6 ) {
document.write ("Aprovado");

} else {

if ( media =< 5 ) {
document.write ("Reprovado");

} else {

document.write ("Recuperação");
}}

</script> 
</head> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

O seu código tem um sinal que esta invertido na comparação:

**Troque:**

> if ( media `=<` 5 ) // errado

**por:**

```
if ( media <= 5 )
```

**Observação:** os sinais de `>` **(maior)** e `<` **(menor)** são sempre antes do `=` **(igual)**.

```js
var media, n1, n2, n3 ;

n1= prompt ("Informe a primeira nota: ") ;
n1= eval (n1) ;

n2= prompt ("Informe a segunda nota: ") ;
n2= eval (n2) ; 

n3= prompt ("Informe a terceira nota: ") ; 
n3= eval (n3) ;

media = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3 ; 

if ( media >= 6 ) 
{
    console.log ("Aprovado");

} 
else 
{ 
    if ( media <= 5 ) 
    {
       console.log("Reprovado");
    }
    else 
    {
       console.log ("Recuperação");
    }
}
```

Dê uma lida nos [operadores de comparação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators).

Answer (score 6):

Refinando o código do Maniero:

```js
var ordinais = ['primeira', 'segunda', 'terceira'];
var media=0;

for (var i = 0; i < ordinais.length; i++) {
    var nota = prompt("Informe a " + ordinais[i] + " nota: ");
    if (nota === "" || !nota) nota = 0;
    media += parseFloat(nota,2);
}

media /= ordinais.length;

if (media >= 6) {
    document.write("Aprovado");
} else if (media <= 5) {
    document.write("Reprovado");
} else {
    document.write("Recuperação");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Há um erro de sintaxe usando o operador de comparação `<=` (menor ou igual). Seguindo a linha da [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159069/101):

```js
var idade = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) idade[i] = parseInt(prompt("Informe a primeira idade: "));
var media = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) media += idade[i];
media /= 3;
if (media >= 6) document.write("Aprovado");
else if (media <= 5) document.write("Reprovado");
else document.write("Recuperação");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Average.js).

Nãos fiz validação se o dado foi digitado errado.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
   var media
   var n1
   var n2
   var n3

   n1 = prompt('informe primeira nota')
   parseFloat(n1)

   n2 = prompt('informe segunda nota')
   parseFloat(n2)

  n3 = prompt('informe terceira nota')
  parseFloat(n3)
  
    media = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3

    if (media >=6){
        alert('aprovado')
    } else {
        if (media <=5)
       alert('reptovado')   
    }
```